# Object of abstract class type "set<std::string>" is not allow:

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, syntax-error, abstract-data-type

I'm using Visual Studios and when I declare a type, its say:
"Error: Object of abstract class type "set< std::string >" is not allow: 
Pure virtual function "setinterface::GetCurrentSize [with type=std::string]" has no overrider"

```
#include <iostream> // For cout and cin
#include <string>   // For string objects
#include "set.h"    // For ADT bag
#include "setinterface.h" // For ADT setinterface
#include <vector> // for vector objects
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   string clubs[] = { "Joker", "Ace", "Two", "Three",
      "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
      "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack",
      "Queen", "King" };

   // Create our bag to hold cards.
   set<string> grabBag;
```

By the time I get to get to set < string > grabBag is when i get this error. Here is the rest of my code

set.h

```
#ifndef TEACH_CSCI235_BAGADT_BAG_H_
#define TEACH_CSCI235_BAGADT_BAG_H_

#include "setinterface.h"

template<class ItemType>
class set : public setinterface<ItemType>
{
 public:
  set(const ItemType& an_item);
  int GetCurrentSize() const;
  bool IsEmpty() const;
  bool Add(const ItemType& new_entry);
  bool Remove(const ItemType& an_entry);
  void Clear();
  bool Contains(const ItemType& an_entry) const;
  vector<ItemType> ToVector() const; 

 private:
  int GetIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const;   
  static const int kDefaultBagSize_ = 6;  
  ItemType items_[kDefaultBagSize_]; // array of bag items
  int item_count_;                    // current count of bag items 
  int max_items_;                 // max capacity of the bag

  // Returns either the index of the element in the array items that
  // contains the given target or -1, if the array does not contain 
  // the target.
};  // end Bag


#endif  // TEACH_CSCI235_BAGADT_BAG_H_



template<class ItemType>
set<ItemType>::set() : item_count_(0), max_items_(kDefaultBagSize_)
{
    return items_[item_count_];
}  // end default constructor

template<class ItemType>
int set<ItemType>::GetCurrentSize() const
{
  return item_count_;
}  // end getCurrentSize

template<class ItemType>
bool set<ItemType>::IsEmpty() const
{
  return item_count_ == 0;
}  // end isEmpty

template<class ItemType>
bool set<ItemType>::Add(const ItemType& new_entry)
{
  bool has_room_to_add = item_count_ < max_items_;

  //compares the new entry to every item in item_ and if there is a duplicate, the loop breaks and nothing is added.
   if (has_room_to_add)
   {
       for ( int i =0; i < max_items_; i++)
        {
            if (items_[i] == new_entry)
                break;  //ends loop

            else if (i==5)
            {
                items_[item_count_] = new_entry;
                item_count_++;
                break;  //ends loop
            }  // end if
        } // end for
   } //end if

  return has_room_to_add;
}  // end add

template<class ItemType>
bool set<ItemType>::Remove(const ItemType& an_entry)
{
  int located_index = GetIndexOf(an_entry);
  bool can_remove_item = !IsEmpty() && (located_index > -1);
  if (can_remove_item)
    {
      item_count_--;
      items_[located_index] = items_[item_count_];
    }  // end if
  return can_remove_item;
}  // end remove

template<class ItemType>
void set<ItemType>::Clear()
{
  item_count_ = 0;
}  // end clear


template<class ItemType>
bool set<ItemType>::Contains(const ItemType& an_entry) const
{
  return GetIndexOf(an_entry) > -1;
}  // end contains

template<class ItemType>
vector<ItemType> set<ItemType>::ToVector() const
{
  vector<ItemType> bag_contents;
  for (int i = 0; i < item_count_; i++)
    bag_contents.push_back(items_[i]);
  return bag_contents;
}  // end toVector

template<class ItemType>
int set<ItemType>::GetIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const
{
  bool found = false;
  int result = -1;
  int search_index = 0;
  // if the bag is empty, item_count is zero, so loop is skipped
  while (!found && (search_index < item_count_))
    {
      if (items_[search_index] == target)
    {
      found = true;
      result = search_index;
    } 
      else
    {
      search_index++;
    }  // end if
    }  // end while
  return result;
}  // end getIndexOf
```

here is all of setinterface.h

```
#ifndef TEACH_CSCI235_BAGADT_BAGINTERFACE_H_
#define TEACH_CSCI235_BAGADT_BAGINTERFACE_H_

#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>
class setinterface
{
public:
   /** Gets the current number of entries in this bag.
    @return The integer number of entries currently in the bag. */
   virtual int GetCurrentSize() const = 0;

   /** Sees whether this bag is empty.
    @return True if the bag is empty, or false if not. */
   virtual bool IsEmpty() const = 0;

   /** Adds a new entry to this bag.
    @post  If successful, newEntry is stored in the bag and
       the count of items in the bag has increased by 1.
    @param new_entry  The object to be added as a new entry.
    @return  True if addition was successful, or false if not. */
   virtual bool Add(const ItemType& new_entry) = 0;

   /** Removes one occurrence of a given entry from this bag,
       if possible.
    @post  If successful, anEntry has been removed from the bag
       and the count of items in the bag has decreased by 1.
    @param an_entry  The entry to be removed.
    @return  True if removal was successful, or false if not. */
   virtual bool Remove(const ItemType& an_entry) = 0;

   /** Removes all entries from this bag.
    @post  Bag contains no items, and the count of items is 0. */
   virtual void Clear() = 0;

   /** Tests whether this bag contains a given entry.
    @param an_entry  The entry to locate.
    @return  True if bag contains anEntry, or false otherwise. */
   virtual bool Contains(const ItemType& an_entry) const = 0;

   /** Empties and then fills a given vector with all entries that
       are in this bag.
    @return  A vector containing all the entries in the bag. */
   virtual vector<ItemType> ToVector() const = 0;
}; // end BagInterface
#endif  // TEACH_CSCI235_BAGADT_BAGINTERFACE_H_
```

I started getting this error right after i tried to create a constructor in the set class and when I went to save it, it gave me a notice that it was gonna use something else in order to save my data, I didn't pay much attention to it but I think that may have something to do with this error.
I'm also suppose to "add a constructor that constructs a Set for a single item:" according to my assignment so my constructor might be a good place to look. I'm not even sure if I did it correctly.
 I appreciate any help. Thankyou!

Comment: `set` is already defined in the `std` namespace so it's probably not a good idea for you to define your own class called `set`.

Comment: Originally it was called Bag but my professor wanted us to name everything as set

Comment: You have a weird greek semicolon (; / U+037E) in your code for some reason.

Comment: The definition of `set`s constructor is fishy: It returns something and doesn't match the declaration (parameters).

Comment: You also haven't declared your default constructor, and the definition even returns a value. Your code compiles after fixing this but it won't link due to the missing function definitions.

Comment: Added the rest of the functions. How did you fix the error?

Comment: try changing `int GetCurrentSize() const;` to `int GetCurrentSize() const override;` - you may get a better error message (if MSVC supports that - IDK whether it does)

Comment: To add to what JonathanPotter said, you should wrap your `set` class in its own namespace so it does not conflict with `std::set`, and get rid of `using namespace std` (bad bad practice!).

Comment: @Bryan - Strange assignment.  You're allowed to use `std::vector`, but not `std::set`.  Man, these C++ instructors sure know how to muck up learning the language.